# Xmlns prefixes after WAS upgrade in web service response

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, websphere-7, websphere-8

thanks a lot for your help. The problem is that I had a WAS upgrade from 7 to 8.5. Before the upgrade this was a typical answer:

> ```
> <SoftwareProductResponse xmlns="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v1.0">
>   <softwareProducts>
>     <productName>WebSphere Application Server</productName>
>     <productSynonym>
>       <productSource>masterSoftwareIndex</productSource>
>       <productName>WebSphere Application Server</productName>
>     </productSynonym>...
>     ...
>     ..
>     .
> ```

And after the WAS upgrade I get the following, notice the prefix "a:" in some tags:

> ```
> <a:SoftwareProductResponse xmlns:a="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v1.0">
>   <softwareProducts>
>     <a:productName>WebSphere Application Server</a:productName>
>     <productSynonym>
>       <a:productSource>masterSoftwareIndex</a:productSource>
>       <a:productName>WebSphere Application Server</a:productName>
>     </productSynonym>...
>     ...
>     ..
> ```

The consumers of this response are too many and I can't ask them to modify their clients to process this new prefixes so I have tried several things trying to completely remove any prefix with no success. I know this is because I have two different namespaces and seems that WAS 8 automatically creates the a and b prefixes. But, why didn't prefixes bother me before in WAS 7?

One important questions is: is it possible to get rid of any prefix when multiple namespaces are in question?

XSDs fragments:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v3.0"
 xmlns:pti="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v3.0"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
 

 <!-- Indicates schema version, which can be used by server to dictate client 
  responses; format is X.YY.ZZ where YY and ZZ can be 00-99 (00 is assumed 
  if there is a single 0) -->
 <simpleType name="PTISchemaVersion">
  <restriction base="string">
   <enumeration value="v1.0.10" />
  </restriction>
 </simpleType>

 <!--============================================================ -->
 <!-- Response related -->
 <!--============================================================ -->

 <!-- Defining responses as elements allows them to be an XML root node for 
  JAXB. -->


 <element name="SoftwareProductResponse" nillable="true"
  type="pti:SoftwareProductResponse" />
 <complexType name="SoftwareProductResponse">
  <sequence>
   <element name="softwareProducts" nillable="true"
    type="pti:SoftwareProduct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </sequence>
 </complexType>

 <complexType name="SoftwareProduct">
  <complexContent>
   <extension base="pti:Product">
    <sequence>
     <element name="productName" nillable="true" type="string"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- Describes primary product names from other "software product name" 
      data sources -->
     <element name="productSynonym" nillable="true"
      type="pti:SoftwareProductSynonym" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
     <!-- Aliases for the product name -->
     <element name="aliases" nillable="true" type="pti:NameAlias"
      minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
     <!-- Human-readable description of the SSP -->
     <element name="description" nillable="true" type="string"
      minOccurs="0" />

     <!-- Associated product codes -->
     <element name="offeringClassificationCode" nillable="true"
      type="pti:OfferingClassificationCode" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="masterSoftwareIndexSynKey" nillable="true"
      type="string" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="questCode" nillable="true" type="pti:QuestCode"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="originalBrandQuestCode" nillable="true"
      type="pti:QuestCode" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="relatedSearchOfferingClassificationCodes"
      nillable="true" type="pti:OfferingClassificationCode" minOccurs="0"
      maxOccurs="unbounded" />

     <!-- Associated miscellaneous properties -->
     <!-- primary brand (generally used for reporting and metrics) -->
     <element name="primaryBrand" nillable="true" type="pti:Brand"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- secondary brands (generally used for on-the-glass organizational 
      purposes) -->
     <element name="secondaryBrands" nillable="true" type="pti:Brand"
      minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
     <element name="owningDivision" nillable="true" type="string"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="productType" nillable="true" type="string"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="masterSoftwareIndexWebShortName" nillable="true"
      type="string" minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- Deprecated as of v1.0.10; instead use productType -->
     <element name="masterSoftwareIndexProductType" nillable="true"
      type="string" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="supportAToZ" nillable="true" type="boolean"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- i.e., indicates the presence of a Q115A IConS template -->
     <element name="supportContentAvailable" nillable="true"
      type="boolean" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="myNotificationsSupport" nillable="true"
      type="boolean" minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- Indicates whether this software product is considered to be a ServiceableSoftwareProduct 
      (SSP) -->
     <element name="ssp" nillable="true" type="boolean"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- Indicates whether this software product is considered to be in 
      preview mode -->
     <element name="preview" nillable="true" type="boolean"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <!-- Indicates whether this software product is expandable (only applicable 
      for SSPs) -->
     <element name="expandable" nillable="true" type="boolean"
      minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="supportURL" nillable="true" type="pti:ReferenceURI"
      minOccurs="0" />

     <!-- Associated VRMs -->
     <element name="vrms" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProductVRM"
      minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

     <!-- Associated ContentComponents (i.e., DCF components) -->
     <element name="contentComponents" nillable="true"
      type="pti:ContentComponent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

     <!-- Defines child software products; only applicable for SSPs -->
     <element name="softwareProductChildren" nillable="true"
      type="pti:SoftwareProduct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

    </sequence>
   </extension>
  </complexContent>
 </complexType>

 <!-- Indicates software product synonyms -->
 <complexType name="SoftwareProductSynonym">
  <complexContent>
   <extension base="pti:PTIBaseType">

    <sequence>
     <element name="productSource" nillable="true"
      type="pti:SoftwareProductSource" minOccurs="0" />
     <element name="productName" nillable="true" type="string"
      minOccurs="0" />
    </sequence>
   </extension>
  </complexContent>
 </complexType>
```

and

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v1.0"
 xmlns:pti="http://w3.ibm.com/xmlns/ibmww/expt/ProductTaxonomyInformation/v1.0"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
 
 <!-- Indicates schema version; can be used by server to dictate client responses -->
 <simpleType name="PTISchemaVersion">
  <restriction base="string">
   <enumeration value="v1.0.0" />
  </restriction>
 </simpleType>
 

 <element name="SoftwareProductResponse" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProductResponse"/>
 <complexType name="SoftwareProductResponse">
  <sequence>
   <element name="softwareProducts" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProduct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
 
 
 <complexType name="SoftwareProduct">
  <complexContent>
   <extension base="pti:Product">
    <sequence>
     <element name="productName" nillable="true" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="productSynonym" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProductSynonym" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     
     <!-- Associated product codes -->
     <element name="offeringClassificationCode" nillable="true" type="pti:OfferingClassificationCode" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="masterSoftwareIndexSynKey" nillable="true" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="questCode" nillable="true" type="pti:QuestCode" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="relatedSearchOfferingClassificationCodes" nillable="true" type="pti:OfferingClassificationCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     
     <!-- Associated miscellaneous properties -->
     <element name="owningDivision" nillable="true" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="masterSoftwareIndexProductType" nillable="true" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="supportAToZ" nillable="true" type="boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
     <!-- i.e., indicates the presence of a Q115A IConS template -->
     <element name="supportContentAvailable" nillable="true" type="boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="myNotificationsSupport" nillable="true" type="boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
     <element name="supportURL" nillable="true" type="pti:ReferenceURI" minOccurs="0"/>
     
     <!-- Associated VRMs -->
     <element name="vrms" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProductVRM" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     
     <!-- Associated ContentComponents (i.e., DCF components) -->
     <element name="contentComponents" nillable="true" type="pti:ContentComponent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
   </extension>
  </complexContent>
 </complexType>
 <!-- Indicates software product synonyms -->
 <complexType name="SoftwareProductSynonym">
  <sequence>
   <element name="productSource" nillable="true" type="pti:SoftwareProductSource" minOccurs="0"/>
   <element name="productName" nillable="true" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
```

SoftwareProductResponse.java:

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SoftwareProductResponse", propOrder = {
    "softwareProducts"
})
public class SoftwareProductResponse {

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
protected List<SoftwareProduct> softwareProducts;

/**
 * Gets the value of the softwareProducts property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the softwareProducts property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getSoftwareProducts().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link SoftwareProduct }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<SoftwareProduct> getSoftwareProducts() {
    if (softwareProducts == null) {
        softwareProducts = new ArrayList<SoftwareProduct>();
    }
    return this.softwareProducts;
}
```

}

What can I do to remove all prefixes?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any workaround or solution for this? I am facing similar issue with WAS 8.5 upgrade.